# Creating MySQL table with Primary-Foreign key relation

Tags: mysql

I have to implement following data model-

```
Table Name:job
Columns-
id(primary key)
version(primary key)
name <datatype>
PK_JOB

Table Name:dependencies
Columns-
id(pfk)
version(pfk)
depends_on_id(pfk)
depends_on_version(pfk)
PK_DEPENDENCIES
FK_JOB_DEPENDENCIES(INT,INT)
FK_JOB_DEPENDENCIES(INT,INT)
```

Iam facing an error while creating second FK relationship.I want to know at first place is it possible that 4 FK reference to 2 Keys?If yes how to achieve the above.It gives me error 121 while creating `FK_JOB_DEPENDENCIES(INT,INT)` the second time.

Comment: Can you post the DDL, please?

Comment: create table job(id int,version int,name varchar(50),constarint PK_JOB primary key(id,version));                                                       create table dependencies(id int,version int,depends_on_job int,depends_on_version int,constraint PK_DEPENDENCIES(id,version,depends_on_id,depends_on_version));                      alter table dependencies add constraint FK_DEPENDENCIES_JOB foreign key(id,version) references JOB(id,version);

Answer (score 1):

A table can have multiple candidate keys. Each candidate key is a column or set of columns that are UNIQUE, taken together, and also NOT NULL. Thus, specifying values for all the columns of any candidate key is enough to determine that there is one row that meets the criteria, or no rows at all.

Candidate keys are a fundamental concept in the relational data model.

It's common practice, if multiple keys are present in one table, to designate one of the candidate keys as the primary key. It's also common practice to cause any foreign keys to the table to reference the primary key, rather than any other candidate key.

I recommend these practices, but there is nothing in the relational model that requires selecting a primary key among the candidate keys.

The below has a composite primary key. One of its columns is auto-incremented. This will work only in MyISAM. InnoDB will generate an error "ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key".

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`animals`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`animals` (
  `grp` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`grp`,`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;

Which returns:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| grp    | id | name    |
+--------+----+---------+
| fish   |  1 | lax     |
| mammal |  1 | dog     |
| mammal |  2 | cat     |
| mammal |  3 | whale   |
| bird   |  1 | penguin |
| bird   |  2 | ostrich |
+--------+----+---------+
```